# printf() não mostra o valor esperado

Tags: c, printf

Estou tendo dificuldades na hora de exibir alguns `printf()`, por exemplo:

```
printf("\nDigite as horas : %d");
```

E na hora de exibir a mensagem, ela aparece com um número do lado, por exemplo:

> Digite as horas: 89676

Qual o erro nisso? Declaro as variáveis corretas, porém na exibição aparece esse número, o que posso fazer para tirá-los?

Comment: Provavelmente ele está lendo alguma região inválida de memória, já que você especificou que iria passar um número como argumento (`%d`) mas não passou nenhum ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/YSkO46) - note que um número diferente foi exibido, pois o conteúdo da memória naquele ponto é indefinido). Se você fizer `printf("\nDigite as horas : %d", 10);` ele vai imprimir `Digite as horas: 10`. Se você não quer nenhum número, retire o `%d` e ele vai imprimir `Digite as horas:`.

Comment: Obrigada Renan, mas já tirei o %d da questão que to fazendo e continua na mesma :/

Comment: Sugiro [edit] a pergunta colocando mais do seu código real, pois somente com esse exemplo fica difícil saber o que realmente está acontecendo...

Comment: @KarolayneSantos Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

É só isto que está a linha mesmo? Então faz sentido aparecer um "lixo" na tela. O `%d` indica que ali será colocado um valor inteiro. Qual valor você está passando para a função para colocar ali? Nenhum. Aí ele pega qualquer coisa que ele achar na memória. Se passar um valor, ele será impresso.

Por outro lado, acho que você está querendo usar a função [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) para ler as horas:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    printf("\nDigite as horas : %d"); //pega qualquer coisa para exibir
    printf("\nDigite as horas : %d", 12); //aqui imprime o 12
    printf("\nDigite as horas :"); //não tem dados variáveis para imprimir
    scanf ("%d", &i); //pede o dado aqui
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/IWcd90). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/umwgxzhz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/PrintfFormat.c).

Comment: O `scanf()` devia ter apenas o `"%d"`. Todos os outros caracteres estao a mais. Alem disso, deve validar sempre o valor devolvido: `if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) /* erro */;`

Comment: É verdade, eu ia montar uma coisa e montei outra na pressa.

Answer (score 0):

Se quer digitar as horas primeiro deve receber as horas por exemplo

```
int main(){
    int horas;
    printf("Digite as horas: ");
    scanf("%d", &horas);
    // Depois devolve o valor lido através de um printf
    printf("São %d horas", horas);
    return 0;
}
```